# Either convert a glob to regex or have Perl handle glob patterns

Tags: regex, perl, glob

I have a config .ini file where users can specify a file pattern either using a Perl regular expression or as an Ant globbing pattern. The following for instance would prohibit a user from creating a file that's not allowed under Windows:

```
[BAN Defined using Ant Globbing]
file = **/prn.*
ignorecase = true

[BAN Defined using Regular expressions]
match = /(aux|con|com[0-9]*|lpt[0-9]*|nul|clock$)\.?[a-z]$
ignorecase = true
```

Right now, I have to convert the glob into a regular expression in order to programmatically handle it. I have a routine that does it, but it's kind of convoluted. I am looking for one of the following:

- An easy way of converting a glob into a regular expression
- Methods of matching glob expressions like you can with regular expressions.

For example:

```
 if ($regex =~ /\/(aux|con|com[0-9]*|lpt[0-9]*|nul|clock$)\.?[a-z]$) {
 if ($glob ?magic? /**/prn.*/) {
```

I was hoping that there is some magical Perl way of doing this. So, is there an easy can't miss way of doing this:

BTW, here's my subroutine in case anyone is interested:

```perl
sub glob2regex {
    my $glob = shift;

    my $regex = undef;
    my $previousAstrisk = undef;

    foreach my $letter (split(//, $glob)) {
        #
        #    ####Check if previous letter was astrisk
        #
        if ($previousAstrisk) {
            if ($letter eq "*") { #Double astrisk
                $regex .= ".*";
                $previousAstrisk = undef;
                next;
            } else {        #Single astrisk: Write prev match
                $regex .= "[^/]*";
                $previousAstrisk = undef;
            }
        }
        #
        #   ####Quote all Regex characters w/ no meaning in glob
        #
        if ($letter =~ /[\{\}\.\+\(\)\[\]]/) {
            $regex .= "\\$letter";
            #
            #   ####Translate "?" to Regular expression equivelent
            #
        } elsif ($letter eq "?") {
            $regex .= ".";
            #
            #   ####Don't know how to handle astrisks until  the next line
            #
        } elsif ($letter eq "*") {
            $previousAstrisk = 1;
            #
            #   ####Convert backslashes to forward slashes
            #
        } elsif ($letter eq '\\') {
            $regex .= "/";
            #
            #   ####Just a letter
            #
        } else {
            $regex .= $letter;
        }
    }
    #
    #   ####Handle if last letter was astrisk
    #
    if ($previousAstrisk) {
        $regex .= "[^/]*";
    }
    #
    #    ####Globs are anchored to both beginning and ending
    #
    $regex = "^$regex\$";
    return $regex;
}
```

Comment: There is http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text::Glob and http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::Glob.  The former gives glob-like matching to regexes, and the latter implements glob-like matching for the filesystem.

Comment: I was hoping for some neat trick that Perl gurus know about, (like being able to interpolate functions in quoted strings via `@{[function]}` syntax) that mere mortals and us second rate programming hacks don't know. I saw `Text::Glob`, but it doesn't expand Ant style expanded globs anyway.

Comment: Could you point to a solid definition of the Ant style glob expansion?  Perhaps a reference point would help conjure a solution.

Comment: In the [Ant Manual](http://ant.apache.org/manual/dirtasks.html#patterns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, there's no neat Perl Guru trick for creating a regular expression from a glob. Drats.

The best I can do is find a CPAN module like [Text::Glob](http://search.cpan.org/~rclamp/Text-Glob-0.09/lib/Text/Glob.pm) that does it. However, `Text::Glob` doesn't do [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/manual/dirtasks.html#patterns) style expanded globbing, so I'd have to modify it anyway. And, the code is no simpler than what I already have.

So, I'm just sticking with what I have.

Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Given that:

1. ? matches exactly one character except '/'
2. * matches zero or more characters except '/'
3. ** matches anything including /

If you don't care about format-checking and some corner cases like '***', then the following strategy, where you first convert special characters to custom-designed escape sequences, then convert the escape sequences to final strings, might work:

```
my $rgx="^$glob\$";
$rgx=~ s|!|!e|g;
$rgx=~ s|[+]|!p|g;
$rgx=~ s|[*]{2}|!d|g;
$rgx=~ s|[*]|!s|g;
$rgx=~ s|[?]|!q|g;
$rgx=~ s|[.]|\\.|g;

$rgx=~ s|!d|.*|g;
$rgx=~ s|!s|[^/]*|g;
$rgx=~ s|!q|[^/]|g;
$rgx=~ s|!p|\\+|g;
$rgx=~ s|!e|!|g;
if ($path =~ m|$rgx|){
    return 1;
}
```